# Auto increment ID in kotlin xml

Tags: xml, kotlin, auto-increment

When I wanted to copy and paste in xml, the id was automatically increasing. I deleted Android Studio and downloaded it again. That feature is gone and I'm having a lot of problems. How can I turn on the auto increment id feature? The current version I'm using is Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

Ai suggested that I find and activate the Auto-increment IDs on paste option, but there is no such option.